# Laravel compare string date in database with carbon date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have made a mistake by storing the date as VARCHAR in the database and here it looks like **02/12/2018** and I have created a variable using carbon to get the current date **+14 days**.

`$current_date_plus_14   = Carbon::now() -> addDay(14) -> format('d/m/Y');`

**Problem is**

I am trying to compare this date **02/12/2018** which is in the database and stores as VARCHAR to the date that I have generated using Carbon which is **09/04/2017**.

**Eloquent Code**

`$gquery = Client::where('required_date', '>=', $current_date_plus_14) -> get();`

**What I get**

It doesn't get any results because it compare only the day in the **required_date** and the day in the **carbon date**.

While it should return value because the there is more than 1 year difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function that converts date as String (May work with varchar) to a real date

```
private function convertDateString($date)
{
    if (is_string($date)) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($date,new DateTimeZone('YOUR_DATE_TIME_ZONE'));
    }

    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your field is a `VARCHAR` instead of `DATETIME` or `DATE`, you can still mark it as a date in your Eloquent model by adding the attribute name to `$dates`. You'll also have to change your model's `$dateFormat` since you have a non-`Y-m-d H:i:s` format.